# is the following syntax evaluating correctly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was wondering if following syntax evaluates as I think it does :

```
Cluster.prototype.test_json_availability = function() {
    return Modernizr.addTest('test_json', function() {
    return (typeof $.browser.msie !== 'undefined' && $.browser.msie === true && $.browser.version < 7 && typeof window.JSON === 'undefined') ? false : true;
    });
};
```

Let's say I do use a MS browser, this means it will return true ? Or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Are your simply testing for the availability of JSON as the method name implies or are the IE tests there for another reason?

Comment: The IE test are for another reason. In case I have an browser MS which version's is less than 7 than it implies a need of JSON fallback, also I need to add history.html4.js if the same statement is meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform the condition by applying [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
function test_json() {
    return typeof $.browser.msie === 'undefined'
      || $.browser.msie !== true
      || $.browser.version > 6
      || typeof window.JSON !== 'undefined';
}
```

This will simplify the condition a lot, and you will be able to find the answer to your question.